# Reference Custom Product template

Tags: bigcommerce

According to the documentation, https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/development-quickstart/rendering-html-with-ajax, I can create a custom template based on a component file, such as products/product-view

What is the base page that contains the front-matter for rendering these components?

The component I am trying to render is not called from any html page using `{{ > component/products/quicker-page }}`. This seems to mean that it will not be included in the `./manifest.json`, and is the root cause of the error displayed in stencil-cli when calling the `getPage` API.

```
window.stencilUtils.api.getPage('/product-1/', { 
  "template": "products/quicker-view" 
}, 
(err, content) => { 
  console.log(content); 
});
```

Error

```
TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'components/products/quicker-view' of undefined
at TemplateAssembler.assemble (C:\Users\bigcommerce\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\server\plugins\renderer\renderer.module.js:466:26)
at getTemplatePaths (C:\Users\bigcommerce\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\template-assembler.js:28:20)
at Async.each.err (C:\Users\bigcommerce\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\template-assembler.js:93:20)
at C:\Users\bigcommerce\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:473:16
at iteratorCallback (C:\Users\bigcommerce\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1064:13)
at C:\Users\bigcommerce\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:969:16
at ReadFileContext.Fs.readFile (C:\Users\bigcommerce\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\lib\template-assembler.js:114:24)
at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Users\bigcommerce\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:90:16)
at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
```

Comment: Do you see that error when bundling, or at a different point? Testing using the example in the docs, I see the `"components/products/quicker-view"` component listed in manifest.json and no bundle errors, but it would be good to understand your process in a bit more detail. https://screencast.com/t/6K0NJg2ar Thanks!

Comment: I see the error at runtime. I am not including {{ > component/products/quicker-page }} in any html file. I am trying to use window.stencilUtils.api.getPage('/product-1/', { "template": "products/quicker-view" }, (err, content) => { console.log(content); })

Comment: Thanks @JJS! Here's the process I'm using to try to replicate: I created component/products/quicker-view based on the quick view component. Then, I ran the getPage function in quick-view.js and the result is a console log of the custom quicker-view template applied to my "scarf" product data: `utils.api.getPage('/scarf/', { 
            "template": "products/quicker-view" 
          }, 
          (err, content) => { 
            console.log(content); 
          });` 
No stencil errors at runtime. Is your template named `quicker-page` or  `quicker-view` or do you have both?

Comment: Should also add--I am not including {{ > component/products/quicker-view }} or {{ > component/products/quicker-page }} in any html file. I _was_ able to replicate the same stencil error you're seeing if I called a template name that didn't exist in the utils function. Let me know if I'm doing anything different when testing and we can go from there!

Comment: I re-edited the OP to make it more clear I'm not referencing the component.
The component I want to render is products/quicker-view.html. I do not also have a template named quicker-page, sorry for the confusion in previous comment.

Comment: Thanks @JJS ! Just 2 more points I wanted to clarify. 1) To confirm, you have created a template file called quicker-view.html located at components/products/quicker-view? 2) Where are you calling the function from? The window. syntax suggests it's being called from the console, but the stack trace suggests it's being called from the template files. Thanks!

Comment: 1. yes, the file exists at the location specified. 2. calling function from browser console, the stack trace appeared to be the result of the call in stencil-cli trying to locate the file.

This is working now, in both window.stencilUtils.api.product.getById and window.stencilUtils.api.getPage. I now cannot reproduce the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KarenWhite I was editing a theme at c:\dev\customer\theme, and stencil-cli was running against c:\dev\cornerstone\. I added a console.log and figured out I was in the wrong place, hence the file wasn't available.

Comment: Mystery solved! Thanks for following up

Comment: Yes. It's painful when you get your projects missed up. Sorry for the wasted time. I need to chase my own red-herrings a little further.

Answer (score 1):

I was editing a different theme than what stencil was running against.

Added some logging to stencil-cli where the exception was coming from (must restart stencil between edits of these files)

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.12.0\node_modules\@bigcommerce\stencil-cli\server\plugins\renderer\renderer.module.js`

```
internals.themeAssembler = {
    getTemplates: (path, processor, callback) => {
        // begin add
        console.log(internals.getThemeTemplatesPath(), path);
        // end add
        TemplateAssembler.assemble(internals.getThemeTemplatesPath(), path, (err, templates) => {
            // begin add
            if (!templates) {
                console.log('templates is empty')
            }
            // end add
            if (templates[path]) {
                // Check if the string includes frontmatter configuration and remove it
                var match = templates[path].match(/---\r?\n[\S\s]*\r?\n---\r?\n([\S\s]*)$/);

                if (_.isObject(match) && match[1]) {
                    templates[path] = match[1];
                }
            }

            callback(null, processor(templates));
        });
    },
    getTranslations: (callback) => {
        LangAssembler.assemble((err, translations) => {
            callback(null, _.mapValues(translations, locales => JSON.parse(locales)));
        });
    },
};
```